# NodeJS streaming - what's the big fuss?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, stream

Forgive me for this stupid question, but I am a bit confused as to what the big fuss is about streaming in NodeJS.

I get that streaming allows us to send chunks of data at a time, improving the experience for the end user

However, isn't this already the standard way in which data is transferred on the Internet? Where, a socket connection is established between the client and the server, and the data is sent via packets?

Socket == stream && and packets == chunks, right?

Answer (score 2):

That's not exactly the point, at all.

You're right in that series of packets are delivered, in point to point HTTP via TCP/IP communication.

But consider sites which allow you to view parts of files, versus sites which force you to wait for the entire file to be ready, prior to starting playback.

The difference is in what the client and server agree is a "complete" document.

In the last example, the file is the complete document.
The server is incapable of (/unwilling to) serving documents any more granular than a full file; ergo, your browser has to wait until the whole file is finished downloading, before it is comfortable using it.

In an alternate universe, a complete "document" may be a set of bytes, which are passed back with header information, specifying where in the total file those bytes fit, allowing for seeking through the document, playing when you have partial content, et cetera.
When the player is running out of buffered content, it will seek the next part, which happens to be a resource consisting of another set of bytes, starting from the byte after its current content.

That has little to do with Node, though, and more to do with HTTP1.1

Other forms of socketed connection (WebSockets, UDP, et cetera) have different behaviours and expectations.

Still little to do with Node, though Node's streams do, indeed, make it easy to support streaming communication between servers, and between clients of one form or another, whether over HTTP or not.

Okay, so with that covered and out of the way...
...what, then, are Node "Streams", if not specifically being about chunked communication?

To get a handle on that, it's easiest to start with the concept of set(/collection) based programming.

Once upon a time, if I had a list of numbers which I wanted to double, I might write something like the following:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var number;
var doubles = [];
var i = 0,
    l = numbers.length;

for (; i < l; i += 1) {
  number = numbers[i];
  doubles.push( number * 2 );
}
```

These days, though, I'd use `.map` to remove all of the loop-management, and instead just focus on the tiny little atomic operation I wanted to apply to each element:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3];
const doubles = numbers.map(x => x * 2);
```

Right?
That's a huge reduction in complexity. And of course, if I wanted to keep chaining extra transforms to the back, I could.

```
numbers
  .map(double)
  .map(add1)
  .filter(gt5)
  .map( ... ) // etc
```

So now that you see that more functional, set-based programming is all about declaring one single operation at a time, on one single element at a time...
...where do streams come in?

Well...  ...what if the array you were mapping and filtering (and reducing) over wasn't finished?
What if it was being filled asynchronously, by some other process, while this system was running?

It might be populated via chunked HTTP1.1 traffic, sure...  ...but that's nowhere near requisite. It could instead be populated by timeout, or a system operation, or a database, or anything else under the sun.

If I had a magical service, which gave me a stream, I might use it like this:

```
// returns a stream which fires on *every* returned row
db.streamQuery( "select * from ........" )
  // turned into domain objects in your system
  .pipe( transformRecordIntoObject )
  // remove private data (DB keys, admin properties, whatever)
  .pipe( removeInternalObjectProperties )
  // remove entries which aren't wanted/helpful, for one reason or another
  .pipe( filterOutUnwantedEntries )
  // buffer entries up, to serve an array of 100 at a time
  .pipe( bufferEvery100AsJSON )
  // send the JSON of 100 results (at a time) straight to the client who requested them
  .pipe( res );
```

As you can see, the streams themselves (which provide the `.pipe`, which accepts a connecting stream) have little to do with HTTP communication...
...that said, they're well suited, and the `req` and `res` objects which you have inside of an HTTP request are indeed readable and writable streams, respectively, and thus, you can pipe from/to them, in this fashion.

I'm intentionally skipping over specific implementation details, and specific communication requirements on the tail end, where I'm shipping bits of JSON over the wire...
...this would require more work for a typical HTTP response (including range-based content streaming), but there wouldn't be much more required than this, for, say, ServerSent Events.

I hope that helps to explain some of the differences between what you might have expected, and what you've been reading...  ...as well as some of the crossover between streaming socket communication, and functional streams which might be found in Node and Scala, terminal command piping in Bash|Powershell|etc, and a few other places.